# several pages Form in jqtouch?

Tags: forms, jqtouch

I'm trying to set up a form in jqtouch with several pages. Basically the user will answer couple questions, go to the next page, answer couple more questions and submit. But Jqtouch doesnt work if I set up one form and put the pages inside of the form tags. Any suggestion how can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. You're probably using a type of master page to do this, try do pages with form tag like you page tag, eg:

```
<form id="home" class="current">
    <div class="toolbar">
        <h1>Title</h1>
        <a class="back hidden" id="btBack" runat="server">Back</a>
    </div>
    <ul>
      ...
    </ul>
</form>
```